# Why I am getting Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting following errors:

```
Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor. (Documentation)  Try removing the reference to the instance member.
The argument type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Vaccination>'. (Documentation)
```

at line `_convertVaccinations(json['vaccinations'] as List<dynamic>));`

Code:

```
final String name;
final String? notes;
final String type;
final List<Vaccination> vaccination;
final String? referenceId;

Pet(this.name, {this.notes, required this.type, required this.vaccination, this.referenceId});

factory Pet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  Pet(
    json['name'] as String,
    notes: json['notes'] as String,
    type:  json['types'] as String,
    referenceId: json['referenceId'] as String,
    vaccination:
      _convertVaccinations(json['vaccinations'] as List<dynamic>));

List<Map<String, dynamic>>? _convertVaccinations(List<dynamic>? vaccinations) {
  if (vaccinations == null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    final vaccinationMap = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
    for (var element in vaccinations) {
      vaccinationMap.add(element.toJson);
    }
    return vaccinationMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include full model class

Comment: please shaer full model class

Comment: updated the model class

Answer (score 0):

### Factory and instance member error:

Well it is because `factory Pet.fromJson(...)` is a factory constructor, and the class method `_convertVaccinations(...)` is an instance member.

If you make `_convertVaccinations(...)` `static`, it will accept the use of it in the factory constructor.

### Argument error:

`vaccination` is of type `List<Vaccination>` and the method `_convertVaccination(...)` returns either `null` or `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

In other words, you cannot assign `null` to `List<T>` unless it says `List<T>?` and the class `Vaccination` is not a `Map<String, dynamic>`

*Maybe* you want to do something like `final List<Vaccination>? vaccinations;` OR return `<Vaccination>[]` instead of `null` if `vaccinations == null`.

So you'd probably want to do write `_convertVaccinations(...)` as:

```
static List<Vaccination>? _convertVaccination(List<dynamic>? vaccinations) {
  return vaccinations?.map((e) => Vaccination.fromJson(e as Map<String,dynamic>).toList();
}
```

or:

```
static List<Vaccination> _convertVaccination(List<dynamic>? vaccinations) {
  return vaccinations?.map((e) => Vaccination.fromJson(e as Map<String,dynamic>).toList() ?? <Vaccination>[];
}
```

Side note: Maybe you have more methods that you haven't presented here. Because it looks a bit wonky when your Pet.**fromJson**(...) use a element.**toJson** down the call stack.